# Как сократить год до 2-х последних цифр?

Tags: php

Допустим, год в переменной `$year` int. Он уже у меня есть, н-р 2014, как эту цифру сократить до 14? Убрать 2 первые цифры.

Comment: в каком виде он там хранится? Строка? int? Data или еще что там PHP для врмени ?

Comment: int. Он уже у меня есть, н-р 2014, как эту цифру сократить до 14? Убрать 2 первые цифры.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да куча способов. `substr($year,2,2)`, например.

Answer (score 3):

```
date('y', strtotime($year));
```

Answer (score 2):

если $year действиельно int как вынаписали то $year = $year - 2000 может тоже сработать, минус в том что работает с годами от 2000 и до 2100 :)

Comment: ну да, поэтому substr($year,2,2) помогает больше. Спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: $year = $year % 100